# Write into an excel cell that already has a value and not write over previous val

Tags: excel, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

Is it possible to write into an excel cell that already has value, and not delete what's already there? So just add to what's already in there.

So for example, I have a for each loop that gets a diff value and I want it all to go into one cell. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.............place a value in cell **A1** and:

```
Sub Addup()
    For i = 1 To 10
    With Range("A1")
        .Value = .Value + i
    End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I got it, thank you. I actually just had to set the value to a variable and it will just add it in the for each loop. So something like this:

 For each match in colmatch
  print match.Value
  i = match.value + i
  datatable.Value("Comments","tresults") = i
 Next

But same concept as you proposed. Thanks again.

Comment: Note that adding numbers is different than adding strings.  It wasn't specified in the original question what the data type was, but if you want to append two string values together, the code would be ".Value = .Value & i" where you use the string concatenation operator (&) instead of the addition operator (+).

Comment: @HgCoder _____Good Comment! ___________the code could be modified to test is the initial value is numeric and use concatenation if it is not.

Comment: @HgCoder I agree! Good point. I should have specified it but I was talking about strings.